# How to Cancel AVExportSession when app goes to background state?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I am having an issue with `AVExportSession` on exporting large files. App will crash during the export when app is in `background` state or in locked state. How to fix this?.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you will need to call `cancelExport` on your exportSession before the app goes into background state or if you're sure it will not take too long, you can register a background task in order to finish the export, which will give your app around a minute to finish before being kicked.

Answer (score 0):

At least for iOS10 or later, the AVExport Session will return a failure with AVError.operationInterrupted when you app resumes. My way of doing it is to just tear everything down and restart the export once that is detected.